# How long does the new Testflight Beta review process usually take?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

iOS app reviews generally take around a week or so. Since Apple now requires that new TestFlight beta apps go through the beta review process as well before we can send it to external testers, I have been wondering how long  this process will take.

**I have just submitted an app for a beta review. What is the timeframe that I should expect the approval (or denial, for that matter) of the beta app to take?**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how apple staffs a queue. If there were something like a physical amount of time or if Apple by policy refused to review anything in less than two weeks, then there would be an actual problem to solve. In this case, the review process depends on staffing and how many apps get submitted and not really anything to do with a specific app.

Comment: @nsij22 OK - let's see if having it opens helps. It will be closed again if it generates too much spam or maintenance efforts.

Comment: A pre-release that was submitted for external tester review last week took, I kid you not, about 5 minutes to be approved. The 2nd submission was waiting for about 12 hours (and was never approved) before we submitted a 3rd version, which has been in review for about 18 hours now with no movement. Very inconsistent.

Comment: For what it's worth here is a mid 2016 answer on the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38396347/294884   It's true that the situation changes often - and it's tricky to get hard facts.

Comment: I can't answer, but here's a comment. Note that changing your version number will trigger a slow review. Updating a build number can be instant.

Comment: Here's a longer discussion/rant: https://christianselig.com/2020/06/testflight-review/

Answer (score 59):

Yesterday at 6 pm I uploaded my beta build for review and it's status was waiting for review. This morning the status had changes to "In review" but now, 13h later it's still "In review". I will update this post if my app build had been approved.

**EDIT:** A day later in the morning it was approved. The total proces from uploading to being reviewed took 1 and a half days.

Comment: One data point does not make an answer.

Comment: Was this over a weekend?

Comment: Generally similar times for me as well, though over the weekend it has taken an extra day or two.

Comment: @IanC. it's infinitely more information than having none though.

Comment: I have already asked test flight related question on SO but did not received any answer, so could you please share your valuable inputs on this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53501307/releasing-intermittent-build-for-external-testers-using-test-flight

Comment: @nipponese According to the answerer, they uploaded it on Sunday, 6pm and it was approved on Tuesday morning.

Comment: @IanC. Do you expect some random stack overflow user to magically have the average amount of time it takes to review? This is as good as it gets

Answer (score 19):

We just submitted our first Beta Review request and were approved in 50 minutes. The app is fairly large and complex. It appears that the Apple testing was very minimal.

Edit to add:
We just release a second version for external beta testing and it was instantly approved; no review required.

Comment: is that for internal testing for external

Comment: External. Internal testing does not require an Apple review.

Comment: External testing does not generally require a review if you did not make significant changes from the previous version.

Comment: Apple requires each new version of the app to be reviewed before they approve it for external testing, but that's only if the version number changes. If you only increment the build number, you can upload as many versions as you want after that first one was approved

Answer (score 12):

It does seem to be shorter than the full review process on average, and actually -- from personal experience -- it seems to be less than 24 hours (don't count on reviews over a weekend or holiday however).  There is a tool for seeing how long a regular review might take [Average App Store Review Times](http://appreviewtimes.com) which is based on voluntarily submitted review time data.  Haven't ever seen it take longer than that though.

Answer (score 11):

In my experience, it depends on the version of your app as well. Generally, first version takes longer and if you have kept the features more or less same, the next version is quickly approved. We submitted first beta version of our app for review last month. **It took one day for Apple to approve first beta release**. From that point onwards, all subsequent beta releases were instantly approved.

Comment: I'm not experiencing this. It's taking more than a few hours for the second beta release to get in review. :/

Answer (score 8):

Apple states, on the [TestFlight Beta Testing page](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/testflight/), that a beta app must comply with the full App Store Review Guidelines in order to be accepted. Based on this, it would be reasonable to expect that the timeframe for review would be about the same.

(That is, of course, assuming they haven't been inundated with a deluge of beta review requests since the feature just became available a few days ago.)

Comment: This is wrong. There's a different process for actual-review and beta-review.

Comment: @JoeBlow Feel free to post an answer if you find mine to be wrong. It was accurate at the time of my post based on the information available.

Comment: indeed @tubedogg now that it's a couple years later - the damned process changes constantly.  (I should have said "this has changed now, yet again" rather than "this is wrong", sorry.)  Just another answer on this ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/38396347/294884

Answer (score 6):

Minimum time it takes is a few hours. Maximum is 3 days (that's what I've experienced). It usually takes longer over the weekends and holidays. In regular days, it usually takes 1 - 1 and a half days. Generally first build of your new version takes longer than the following builds especially if there is a major change. All information written is from experience only. It will differ in your case.

Answer (score 5):

I had a beta release approved for TestFlight today in around an hour.

Comment: that was my case for most builds as well